# How to have Eclipse intellisense autocomplete member names?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type in a method name partially, Eclipse intellisense shows me the list of suggestions, but how do I select one of them using only the keyboard?

I tried pressing the `Tab` key, the `Enter` key and the `Space` bar, but all to no avail. It appears that the only way I can get to select one of the names from the list of suggestions is to use the mouse. This is very irritating.

Is there a keyboard short-cut to selecting a name from the intellisense suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I dont get your problem. When I write code in eclipse, and for example put "this." somewhere; I get a popup with reasonable completions. And I just use the cursor keys to select the one I need.

Comment: @GhostCat Once you *have selected* which one to use using the cursor keys, how do you make that method appear in the editor? That's my question.

Comment: Have you tried the arrow keys?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, but they only navigate through that list. Which key do I press to have the one I have navigated to appear in the editor and to dismiss the pop-up that lists the suggestions?

Comment: Enter key is supposed to work. Could it be that your Enter key mapped to something a bit unusual? Did you try the regular Enter vs numeric keypad's Enter?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous between "highlight on the list" and "activate the completion". For me, Enter works; this may be configurable in the key bindings.

Comment: @chrylis The `Enter` key *just now* started working for me, too. I think I might have tried too hard and when I tried hitting the `Enter` key the previous times, the focus must have been someone else, for e.g. in the help tool tip window because I might have used a lot of arrow key or tab key strokes by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in some part of the expression, use the arrow keys to navigate through the suggestions offered by intellisense. And then hit the `Enter` key to select the chosen expression, dismiss the pop-ups and have the selected expression appear in the editor in place of your partially typed expression.

Do *not* hit the tab key before making a selection as that moves focus away from the suggestions window.